# Как подключить фокус к компонентам xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, storyboard

Добрый день, подскажите, как подключить фокус к визуальным компонентам в xcode osx(nsbutton, checkbox, edit ...)? Задействовать кл вверх вниз вправр влево таб shift.

Comment: что такое фокус в данном контексте?

Comment: навигация без мышки  в приложении только с помошью клавиш таб, enter :) к примеру имея окно с контролами  "введите имя", ок, отмена получить возможность выбрать , без мышки , без горячих клавиш привязанных к конкретному контролу, либо "поле ввода" , либо кнопку ок, либо отмена. Для этого пользователь должен видеть текущий контрол (фокус) и уметь его менять.

Comment: Потыкал в storyboard. Поля ввода работают с фокусусом по умолчанию. А button, check, radiobutton не нет. Вопрос: почему и как?

Comment: Смог увидеть требуемое при включении voiceower!!

Comment: Стало быть , если voiceover включен, требуется с ним синхронизация

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию переключаться между контролами можно только с помощью клавиши Tab.

Для этого назначьте тот контрол, на котором фокус должен оказаться первым, как initialFirstResponder соответствующего компонента. Если ваш компонент - NSWindowController, то это нужно сделать в методе windowDidLoad:, если это NSViewController - то во viewDidLoad:.

После этого установите значение аутлета nextKeyView у каждого контрола на следующий контрол, куда должно происходить переключение. То есть, если с поля textField1 надо переключаться на textField2, то у textField1 ставите nextKeyView = textField2. Это можно сделать и в Interface Builder, и из кода.

После этого переключение должно работать автоматически, поддерживается даже создание циклов из переходов. Однако, если есть необходимость перемещать фокус на кнопки и другие контролы, кроме текстовых полей и списков, то необходимо включить дополнительную опцию в настройках: System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Full Keyboard Access -> All controls.

При необходимости поддерживать другие клавиши, кроме Tab, есть смысл отлавливать их нажатия отдельно и менять свойство firstResponder у текущего корневого компонента.